# Texshop synctex inverse search

Tags: pdftex, texshop, forward-inverse-search

I'am running pdflatex from Texshop 3.18 on OS X 10.8.4 with Synctex and the inverse search is not working, meaning from the output pdf back to the source window. Command left clicking the pdf does nothing.

The opposite, from source to preview is not a problem.

As detailed in an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116912/texshop-and-inverse-search/116923#116923), I've set the sync method to `synctex` and pdflatex is configured as follows:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --syncteX=1
```

Comment: Are you sure about `--syncteX=1`? It should be `--synctex=1`

Comment: @egreg, I changed it as you suggested and it unfortunately makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry, but on my machine it works.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem here, with os x 10.7 too, not only with 10.8.
As suggested in http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/TeXShop_Synchronization
I have added to this line in the ENGINE preferences

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --synctex=1
```

the option

```
--synctex=1
```

so that the result now is

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --synctex=1
```

And now the `synctex` is well.