# Inverse search in texshop is broken -- perhaps after tlmgr update

Tags: texshop, forward-inverse-search

I'm a new mac user. When I tried TexShop after my fresh MacTex install, the inverse search (CMD+click from pdf to source) worked perfectly. Now it doesn't work. I suspect it stopped working when I did a `tlmgr update --all`, but I may be wrong. I looked at the following question: [Texshop and inverse search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116912/texshop-and-inverse-search?lq=1) and I checked what the accepted answer says, everything was alright.

Comment: Which version of TeXShop do you use now? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: The latest version.

Comment: Would that be version `3.23`? One reason to provide specific information on versions is that your posting may become unintelligible in a few weeks if and when the version changes to whatever is the "latest version"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. I'm answering my own question because I think it might be useful to others.

The thing is, for SyncTeX (the latex package responsible for search and inverse-search) to work, you have to **compile the .tex file** with the program you're using!