# texshop 3.62 sync not working with Mac OSX 10.11.5

Tags: texshop, forward-inverse-search

Right-click 'sync' of highlighted words or phrases in TeXshop 3.62 under Mac OSX 10.11.5 has no effect, either from source or output. No errors appear, simply nothing happens. In the Typesetting preferences, the 'SyncTeX (TeX >= 2010)' option is selected (per other responses on this site). What could I be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It's Cmd-Left Click, not Right Click.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me either. So far I've tried highlighting the word and using <sync> from the drop-down box, cmd-left click and cmd-right click. None work. Is this a known bug in TeXshop 3.62?

Comment: Like magic, it now works as expected. thanks all.

Comment: It doesn’t work for me either, even after setting the prefs per http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116912/texshop-and-inverse-search

Comment: @FlashSheridan - I am having the same problem, running TexShop 3.75 on Mac OSX Sierra (10.12.3). Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @benblumsmith:  I don't think so, I believe I just kept using TeXMaker until the article got published.

Comment: I had the same problem, turns out it doesn't work right after you open a file, you need to compile it first. Maybe it can help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

"Alternatively, adding a line 
\synctex=1
in the preamble of a tex file triggers the synchronization with SyncTeX, not only with pdflatex, but with other TeX commands too."
(http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/SyncTeX)

I tried this suggestion and it seems to work!